# Unable to disable Msurguy Honeypot in Unit test in Laravel

Tags: laravel, honeypot

I am developing a Laravel application. I am doing unit testing on my application as well. I am also implementing Honeypot on the forms as well using this package, https://github.com/msurguy/Honeypot. It is working when I submit the form from the browser. But the thing is I need to disable it in the unit test. I am trying to do it following what is mentioned in the docs like this.

```
Honeypot::disable();
```

But when I run my test, I got this error.

```
ErrorException: Non-static method Msurguy\Honeypot\Honeypot::disable() should not be called statically
```

What is wrong? Is the documentation wrong or how can I possibly do that?
That is what exactly mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the facade statically, not the service class directly.

Instead of this:

```php
use Msurguy\Honeypot\Honeypot;

// ...

Honeypot::disable();
```

Do:

```php
use Msurguy\Honeypot\HoneypotFacade as Honeypot;

// ...

Honeypot::disable();
```

Or:

```php
// ...

\Honeypot::disable();
```